# can we update ViewController from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken by checking isRegisteredForLocalNotifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, viewcontroller, appdelegate

Hi i am new in iOS application development. I am using Swift 3.0 code.

In my application I'm fetching the device token and I'm passing to my server. to pass token value from Appdelegate to UIViewController i am using UserDefaults.standard. and it's working fine. During first application load i am showing system's push notification prompt. If user click OK (allow) or Don't allow. application check it using following code.

```
 //Checking Notification State
    let isRegisteredForLocalNotifications = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types.contains(UIUserNotificationType.alert) ?? false

    if isRegisteredForLocalNotifications{
        print("Notification allow")
    }else{
        print("Notification Don't allow")
    }
```

Note: The above code is working fine in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken.

I am having following issue with above code.

1) if i am using same code in ViewController its working but my application not waiting for system's push notification prompt result. i am getting results in AppDelegate.

So **how to reload ViewController from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken?** is there any way to do that.

2) **can i pause viewController until user response to system's push notification prompt.** But i am not sure above code will work in ViewController or not.

Please advise.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

For first part of your problem, you can create an Observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

the function that handle it will be like this:

```
 func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification){
    //Take Action on Notification
 }
```

and then you can call it as follows:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

you can call the above code whenever you want to update your viewController

Answer (score 1):

You can update view controller from  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken? by post notification.

```
let notificationIdentifier: String = "NotificationIdentifier"

//write this to didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
// Post notification
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
 //write this to your View Controller
 let notificationIdentifier: String = "NotificationIdentifier"

// Register to receive notification
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(YourClassName.methodOfReceivedNotification), name: notificationName, object: nil)



// Stop listening notification
 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: notificationName, object: nil);


func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification) {
}
```